# react object state not rerendering the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i have an object state:

```
  const [checkboxarray_final, setCheckboxarray_final] = useState({
    2: ",4,,5,",
    9: ",1,",
  });
```

i am trying to do check/uncheck for multiple checkbox:

this is my functions:
the first one to check if key is in object

the second one to check if value exist in the key

the 3 one is to return true(checked), false (uncheck)

the 4 one is to update the state

```
function isKeyInObj(obj, key) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(key);
  }

  function getValueFromKeyInObj(obj, key) {
    return obj[key];
  }
  const checkboxChecker = (catid, itemid) => {
    const first = isKeyInObj(checkboxarray_final, catid);
    if (first) {
//check if value is related to the object
      if (
        getValueFromKeyInObj(checkboxarray_final, catid).includes(`,${itemid},`)
      ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
  const handleCheck = (catid, itemid) => {
//check again if key in object
    const first = isKeyInObj(checkboxarray_final, catid);
    if (first) {
// check if value is related to the object
      if (
        getValueFromKeyInObj(checkboxarray_final, catid).includes(`,${itemid},`)
      ) {
//to remove it (uncheck)
        let newobj = { ...checkboxarray_final };
        newobj[catid] = newobj[catid].replace(`,${itemid},`, "");
        setCheckboxarray_final(newobj);

        console.log(newobj, "ggg");
      } else {
//to add it to existing parent key
        let newobj = { ...checkboxarray_final };
        newobj[catid] = newobj[catid] + `,${itemid},`;
        setCheckboxarray_final(newobj);

        console.log(newobj, "hhh");
      }
    } else {
//add the key and the value
      let newobj = { ...checkboxarray_final };
      newobj[catid] = `,${itemid},`;
      setCheckboxarray_final(newobj);
      console.log(checkboxarray_final, "jjj");
    }
  };
```

here is my checkbox component:

```
<CheckBox
                                checked={checkboxChecker(
                                  key,
                                  value
                                )}
                                checkBoxStyle={{
                                  checkedColor: "#004b8d",
                                  size: 15,
                                  unCheckedColor: "#b8b8b8",
                                }}
                                duration={400}
                                onClick={() =>
                                  handleCheck(key, value)
                                }
                              />
```

in my console, the state is updated but not rending until i do another uncheck/check, the the previous action is rendering.

any help?

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, for example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: What exactly is the goal? Is it to create a working CheckBox component, or handle checkbox values on a form submission, or something else? I don't know if I can solve your issue without know the goal.

Comment: onchange checkbox to update check/uncheck. by checking if the checkbox value is a part of key value, which is a string. example: the checkbox value is 2, the value of key in the state is ',2,,3,,4,'... so i am converting 2 to ,2, and check if string inclues(',2,')

Comment: @michael Okay. That makes sense. I think I can help you, but if I may ask, why do you want the state to be in that `,x,,y,,z,` format, when you could use an array?

Comment: The backend is returning a row with column named features. And it handles multiple features that way as a string. ,2,,3, for example 2 and 3 are two different featured, so i need to compare with the features column

Comment: I've got a working CodePen here: [Working Version](https://codepen.io/andrilla/pen/OJoNGoz?editors=1011). I don't have time to provide a full explanation today, but I'll write on tomorrow. I hope this helps in the meantime.

Comment: i understand your code, thanks. i will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the code to run in stack overflow, but you can see it working in CodePen. Here's some explanation.

---

#### The Checkbox

First, with the `Checkbox`, you provided:

```
<CheckBox
  checked={checkboxChecker(
    key,
    value
  )}
  checkBoxStyle={{
    checkedColor: "#004b8d",
    size: 15,
    unCheckedColor: "#b8b8b8",
  }}
  duration={400}
  onClick={() =>
    handleCheck(key, value)
  }
/>
```

So based on your use of the component, I made the component like this:

```
function Checkbox(props) {

  // Somewhere in here, I assume you build the styles based on the checkBoxStyle prop
  const checkboxStyles = {props.checkBoxStyle}

  return (
    {`/* The onClick runs the handleCheck function */`}
    <div style={checkboxStyles} onClick={props.onClick}>
      {`/* The input displays a checkbox, and displays checked, based on the checkboxChecker function */`}
      <input type="checkbox" checked={props.checked} />
      {`/* I added a label, for the demonstration */`}
      <label>{props.label}</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

#### The Functionality

Now we get into the actual functionality, based on my understanding of the component above—mainly just the `onClick`.

###### Number to Array

First, for this demonstration, I created a function that returns an array from any given number. You probably wouldn't use it in your case. I'm just using it as a simple way of changing up the checkbox options in the demo.

```
/**
 * ### Number to Array
 * - Returns an array with the specified number of items
 * @param {number} number
 * @returns {any[]} An array with the specified number of items
 */
const numberToArray = (number) => {
  // Create an empty array
  const array = []
  // Loop through the specified number of items
  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    // Push an item to the array
    array.push(i)
  }
  // Return the array
  return array
}
```

###### The Demo

```
function App() {

  const [checkboxarray_final, setCheckboxarray_final] = useState({
    2: ",4,,5,",
    9: ",1,",
  });

  /**
   * ### Handle Check
   *
   * Updates the `checkboxarray_final` state by toggling the value of `itemid` for the given `catid`.
   *
   * @param {string} catid - The ID of the category in which the checkbox needs to be updated.
   * @param {number} itemid - The ID of the checkbox.
   */
  const handleCheck = (catid, itemid) => {
    setCheckboxarray_final((prev) => {

      // First we get the previous value of the category
      const oldValue = prev[catid] || ''

      // Now we set the new value based on whether the oldValue has the itemid
      const newValue = oldValue.includes(`,${itemid},`)
                       ? oldValue.replace(`,${itemid},`, '') // If it has the itemid, we remove it
                       : `${oldValue},${itemid},`; // If it doesn't have the itemid, we add it

      // The value returned keeps the previous value of all other categories, and sets the selected category to the new value
      return { ...prev, [catid]: newValue };
    });
  };

  /**
   * ### Checkbox Checker
   *
   * Returns a boolean indicating whether the specified item is checked in the specified category.
   *
   * @param {string} catid - The ID of the category to check.
   * @param {number} itemid - The ID of the item.
   * @returns {boolean} - Whether the item is checked.
   */
  const checkboxChecker = (catid, itemid) => {
    return (checkboxarray_final[catid] || '').includes(`,${itemid},`);
  };

  // Use the Object.entries() method to create an array of key-value pairs from checkboxarray_final for use later
  const arrayOfEntries = Object.entries(checkboxarray_final)

  // This should be an array of strings, representing each option
  // For simplicity in the demonstration, I'm using a function to convert a number into an array
  const options = numberToArray(5)

  return (
    <div>
      {`/* To render the categories and values, we use the arrayOfEntries variable, and use the map() method to iterate over each pair. */`}
      {arrayOfEntries.map(([key, value]) => (
        <div key={key}>
          <h3>Category: {key}</h3>
          {`/* Now we take our options array and loop through them with the map() method, to create each checkbox */`}
          {options.map((item) => (
            <Checkbox
              key={item}
              checked={checkboxChecker(key, item)}
              checkBoxStyle={{
                checkedColor: "#004b8d",
                size: 15,
                unCheckedColor: "#b8b8b8",
              }}
              onClick={() => handleCheck(key, item)}
              label={item}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hopefully this explanation helps. Let me know if you have any questions.